# JavaScript - Factorial explanation

Tags: javascript, recursion, factorial

I wanted someone to basically help me understand what each line of code is doing and help me comment each line (if applicable) so that it can help explain to another person what it's doing. It'd be awesome if one can just give second eyes and ensure that the code is actually good - I'm trying to get my head around Factorial/Recursion, and did some research and found these solutions for this.

I was given this scenario:

*For positive n, factorial is n! = n*(n−1)!   (e.g. 5! = 5 * 4
* 3 * 2 * 1)*

Here's what I've found for this scenario:

```
// Prompt user to enter a number to calculate the factorial
var num = prompt("What number do you want to find the factorial of?");

var factorial = function(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        product = 1;
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            product *= i;
        }
        return product;
    }
}
console.log(factorial(num));
```

**Recursive**

*Create a recursive algorithm to calculate the factorial using every second
number as shown in examples below:*

5! = 5 * 3 * 1 = 15
6! = 6 * 4 * 2 = 48

As for the cursive part, this is added onto the above code and is written in the following -

```
//  recursive
var factorial = function(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
console.log(factorial(num));
```

Would appreciate your assistance on this - Apologies if this has already been answered, please direct me to another thread if this has been already posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion for that:

```
/**
 * Calculate factorial, optionally using a difference other than 1 with previous value.
 * Example: factorial(6, 2) // 6*4*2 = 48
 */
var factorial = function(n, d) {
  if (!d) {d = 1;}
  var product = 1;
  while (n > 1) {
    product *= n;
    n -= d;
  }
  return product;
};

console.log(factorial(6, 2)); // 48
console.log(factorial(6)); // 720
```

Note: Declare local variables inside the function with keyword 'var'. Otherwise they become globals and the second time you attempt to use a function may produce wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, writing a function for Factorial is an exercise on writing recursive function. The first example code is not recursive and just an overly complicated way of calculating a factorial by multiplying the numbers iteratively so I'll skip that.

The second code is recursive, and it is following the recursive definition of factorial in your usual mathematics:

```
f: N => N, f(x) = x! = { x < 1 : 1, else : x (x - 1)! }
```

Or equivalently in JavaScript:

```
let fac = n => n < 1 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1);
```

An expansion of an example computation would look like:

```
5!
5(4!)
5(4(3!))
5(4(3(2!)))
5(4(3(2(1))))
5(4(3(2(1(0!)))))
5(4(3(2(1(1)))))
120
```